# Sharepoint unable to query security group members from AD?

Tags: error, security, domain, credentials

I have a sharepoint environment with multiple domains, access to the site is given on each domain by an AD security group on the remote domain.

The newest domain has a security group that has been allowed access the same way, however when the users in that group login to the site they get the 'access denied' error.

Sharepoint can query the domain to get the credentials of the accounts, and if an account from that domain is given permissions directly (as opposed to the entire group) it will login successfully.

Does anyone know what can cause this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an AD expert, but we experienced something similar recently. We solved it by making the group a universal security group. Possibly [also Global scope would work](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserversecurity/thread/693eeb9c-37b8-48aa-a473-31e84a6074d8).

Comment: yes, this appears to be the case. The security group was created as a 'domain local' group. thank you very much!